# Visualize JSON models as domain model

Tags: json, data-visualization, domain-model

Is there a way to display a bunch of JSON objects, WITH relations, as a domain model?

Models could be something like this:

```
{
  "name": "Order",
    "status": {
      "type": "number",
      "null": false,
      "default": 1
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "customer": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Customer",
      "foreignKey": "customerId"
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, as this image shows, Domain model -to-> code... but the other way around.?

[image]

Thanks

PS: If there are no tools that do this out of the box, I assume that there might be frameworks that I could use to create this.. any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question you are asking if a utility exists that can turn your JSON code into a domain model. If I understand correctly the answer is yes. There is one project on github that is doing something similar: [json-discoverer](https://github.com/SOM-Research/jsonDiscoverer)

From the project page you will see the tool was inspired by some research which was published in ICWE (International Conference on Web Engineering) 2013 and 2014. Below is a link to the main article, as it is quite lengthy and detailed I will not attempt to summarize it here.

- [Discovering Implicit Schemas in JSON Data](http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/81/89/45/PDF/icwe2013-CanovasCabot.pdf)

Unfortunately, as you mention you can't then edit the domain afterward. But I have still found it to be a fairly useful tool.

I am unaware of any other existing utilities. The only other alternatives are fairly easy to find with a simple search, but only allow for conversion to trees and/or tables.